# Create VOIP chat application using Socket.IO

Tags: ionic-framework, socket.io, chat, voip

I am currently working on a chat application which lets you chat using VOIP protocol. Briefly I want to make an application like Skype where you  are able to make a video call.

Can I use socket io to create this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can** you. Yes. **Should** you? Probably not.

socket.io is a real-time messaging library that's great for binary data and lightweight objects (strings, json, etc). If you're wanting to do audio and video as well you're better off using some sort of media server that has better protocol support for jitter, latency, etc.

You could build some of this on top of socket.io but there's a reason it hasn't been done. All of that extra overhead would make things far more less efficient than using some other protocol specifically built for realtime multimedia.

Edit: If you're familiar with piping in the Linux world you can try piping from a process to socket.io and then piping the output on the other end back into another process. I've done this before for a quick and dirty audio transport.

Comment: Perfect answer, should be set as answer imo. Ionic is capable of handling the voice part. But Socket.IO might not be the best pipe.